# yield between different processes

Tags: linux, multithreading, boost, g++, yield

I have two C++ codes one called *a* and one called *b*. I am running in in a 64 bits Linux, using the Boost threading library.

The *a* code creates 5 threads which stay in a non-ending loop doing some operation.
The *b* code creates 5 threads which stay in a non-ending loop invoking yield().

I am on a quadcore machine... When a invoke the *a* code alone, it gets almost 400% of the CPU usage. When a invoke the *b* code alone, it gets almost 400% of the CPU usage. I already expected it.

But when running both together, I was expecting that the *b* code used almost nothing of CPU and *a* use the 400%. But actually both are using equals slice of the CPU, almost 200%.

My question is, doesn't yield() works between different process? Is there a way to make it work the way I expected?

Comment: I don't have an answer, and I think your question is interesting because sched_yield claims to put the process on the back of the run queue, but this might be interesting to you in terms of calling into question the actual usefulness of using sched_yield: http://kerneltrap.org/Linux/Using_sched_yield_Improperly

Comment: This book snippet implies that the version of your linux kernel matters: http://books.google.com/books?id=k_ocKY0iegsC&pg=PA168&lpg=PA168&dq=sched_yield+to+another+process&source=bl&ots=VgCNK6kGIu&sig=gyduzTS_2EY8v8wwwAE8MScSLsg&hl=en&ei=68N7TqfOCcXPiAK6qrDVBw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=sched_yield%20to%20another%20process&f=false

Comment: This is expected. That is because [for modern systems `sched_yield` is badly defined and people shouldn't be using it](https://www.realworldtech.com/forum/?threadid=189711&curpostid=189752).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linux uses dynamic thread priority. The static priority you set with nice is just to limit the dynamic priority.

When a thread use his whole timeslice, the kernel will lower it's priority and when a thread do not use his whole timeslice (by doing IO, calling wait/yield, etc) the kernel will increase it's priority.

So my guess is that process *b* threads have higher priority, so they execute more often.

Answer (score 3):

So you have 4 cores running 4 threads that belong to A. There are 6 threads in the queue - 1 A and 5 B. One of running A threads exhausts its timeslice and returns to the queue. The scheduler chooses the next runnable thread from the queue. What is the probability that this tread belongs to B? 5/6. Ok, this thread is started, it calls sched_yield() and returns back to the queue. What is the probability that the next thread will be a B thread again? 5/6 again!

Process B gets CPU time again and again, and also forces the kernel to do expensive context switches.

sched_yield is intended for one particular case - when one thread makes another thread runnable (for example, unlocks a mutex). If you want to make B wait while A is working on something important - use some synchronization mechanism that can put B to sleep until A wakes it up